# Radio input selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, radio-button

I have a quiz app and I use customized radio buttons (using CSS) for the answers, but I want to change the color of the radio buttons if the answer is correct or incorrect. I need to find how to take this CSS selectors on jQuery

```
input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check

input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check::before
```

here is my function

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
        var radioValue = $("input[name='selector']:checked").val();
        $("input:radio").attr('disabled',true);
        if(radioValue === correctAnswer[questionCounter - 1]){

           $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").addClass("correct");


            $("#points").empty();
            points = points + 10;
            $("#points").append("Points: " + points);

        } else {

            $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").addClass("incorrect");
            $("#correctA").append("Correct answer is: " + correctAnswerText[questionCounter - 1]);

        }
    });
```

I can change the label of the radio button but to change the radio button color I need to select the css selectors on top

Comment: here is the code working https://github.com/zorazky/quiz.git I can change the color of the label but not on the circle and the dot

Answer (score 0):

Just give them a class and then use the `onchange` event to see if they're checked:

```
$( ".rbs" ).change(function() {
    if ($( "#rb1" ).is(':checked')) {
        $( "#rb1Lbl" ).css('color', 'green');
        $( "#rb2Lbl" ).css('color', 'red');
    } else {
        $( "#rb2Lbl" ).css('color', 'green');
        $( "#rb1Lbl" ).css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pedromendessk/5febzk6x/) to see if it's something like this that you want

Comment: thanks for your help, my problem is to take the objects I post in jquery, add the class is not the problem is to select the objects

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding what you mean. You want to change the checked state with JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

In similar situation I've removed redundant classes before add needed. If I were at your place I would try use something like following

$("input[name='selector']:checked").removeClass( "incorrect" );
$("input[name='selector']:checked").addClass( "correct" );